# Separate similar errors into different messages in java application using atlassian.oai.validator

Tags: java, openapi

I am trying to make OpenApi validation in my Java application and faced with some problems.

When I get errors like

```
"id": "57ec990e-c3f0-4cb9-a402-128fcbe8e9ff",
"messages": [
    "Object has missing required properties ([\"author\",\"publisher\"])"]
```

But I need to separate similar errors like this

```
"id": "57ec990e-c3f0-4cb9-a402-128fcbe8e9ff",
"messages": [
    "Object has missing required property \"author\",
    "Object has missing required property \"publisher\"
    ]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you use a specific validation library/framework? If so, which one?

Comment: i am using swagger request validator from com.atlassian.oai.validator